# Webpage showing PHP code instead of parsing it

Tags: php, apache

I recently reinstalled Apache and now my PHP code is shown directly instead of being ran. For example, if I go to example.com/info.php, all I see is:

`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

I double checked PHP wasn't uninstalled. Is there some configuration setting somewhere I'm missing?

### Solution (question is not duplicate)

This problem was because after the new install of Apache, the modules were not configured correctly. Something about thread vs events. Anywho, run these commands:

```
a2dismod mpm_event
a2enmod mpm_prefork
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Now my php works perfectly

Comment: Have you checked your file extension? It should be "file_name.php" not "file_name.html"

Comment: Yes, it's all php. All these webpages were working before the Apache reinstall

Comment: If you reinstalled Apache, you may need to re-enable/re-install mod_php (how to do so depends on your OS)

Comment: Went hunting for a solution. Ended up enabling a php7.0 mod. Now my apache won't start

Answer (score 1):

check the apache configuration:

ensure that in your httpd.conf you have the line `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` `or  LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so`

if you're using php7
check that in apache configuration there is something similar to

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

check that starting apache you don't have error messages (some broken path or some mistype in configuration or similar)

source: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: I'm using php5.0. And adding that LoadModule line to apache2.conf will prevent apache from restarting